# How to print the variable outside of the function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to `alert(httpAccept)` outside of the function but this is not possible. All actions must me made inside the `httpAcceptResponse(data)`.

When I consol httpAccess after the getHTTP() I get

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.domain.com/httpaccept.php?callback=httpAcceptResponse".

What is a workaround for this?

```
function requestServerCall(url) {
  var head = document.head;
  var script = document.createElement("script");

  script.setAttribute("src", url);
  head.appendChild(script);
  head.removeChild(script);
}



var httpAccept = '';

function httpAcceptResponse(data) {
  httpAccept = data.token;
}

function getHTTP() {
  requestServerCall("http://www.domain.com/httpaccept.php?callback=httpAcceptResponse");
}

getHTTP();
```

Comment: There is none.  You are making a JSONP call (or at least appending a script to the `<head>`).  It's asynchronous, so you need to do anything related to the data in the callback.  One way is to pass a callback when you request the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind a callback. Something like:

```
var httpAcceptResponse;
function getHTTP(callback) {
  httpAcceptResponse = callback;
  requestServerCall("http://www.domain.com/httpaccept.php?callback=httpAcceptResponse");
}

getHTTP(function(data) {
  console.log(data.token);
  // now you have the variable
});
```

Edit: If you want to use it globally, set it in the callback:

```
getHTTP(function(data) {
  window.httpAccept = data.token;
});
```

Note, however, that the variable is not available globally until the callback is called.

Comment: oh thank you.. I have two questions, at the first example, the requestServerCall is executed 1 time only, correct? The second question for the second example, is, how do I print it outside? Because I tried `alert(window.httpAccept)` outside the function and got undefined

Comment: @Fataoulas: That's the issue here.  You *can't* access it globally.  Because it's being retrieved *asynchronously*.  You need to *wait* until the call is done, and that's why you use callbacks.  P.S. You may need to change your design if you are using asynchronous calls in JavaScript.  It's a different paradigm.

Comment: @Fataoulas: *"Because I tried alert(window.httpAccept) outside the function and got undefined"* And we are back at square one: You are trying to read the value **before** the callback was called. While it is possible the access it "outside" you don't really know *when* you can access if you don't work with the callback.

Comment: @Fataoulas I think you are having an "xy problem". Instead of asking  "how do I access it outside", try thinking about "when do I need it and how should I make sure it's available before that time". If you still need help, post a new question specifying what you're trying to do with the `httpAccept` variable.